# Python dataframe - proper date indexing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I can't get my head around this. After importing a csv time series with dates and prices as a dataframe, I want to index the date column.

```
df = pd.read_csv("pricespanda.txt")

        Date  Price1  Price2
0   1-1-2017     100     101
1   2-1-2017     103     102
2   3-1-2017     109     116
```

I have tried:

```
df = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date']))

df = df.loc[:,['Price1','Price2']]
```

but what I get is:

```
            Price1  Price2
Date                      
2017-01-01     100     101
2017-02-01     103     102
2017-03-01     109     116
```

Whilst what I want is:

```
            Price1  Price2               
2017-01-01     100     101
2017-02-01     103     102
2017-03-01     109     116
```

How can I achieve this please; after indexing the date column keeps the name "Date"...I can't seem to be able to get rid of it...

Comment: Please next time provide a *sample* **csv**-file, so we can easily load the data locally and experiment with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can **set the name of the index to `None`**:

```
df.index.rename(None, True)
```

The `True` specifies that we do this inplace. We then got:

```
>>> df.index.rename(None, True)
>>> df
          Price1  Price2
1-1-2017     100     101
2-1-2017     103     102
3-1-2017     109     116
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not solve the issue...how can I get rid of this "Date" column heading altogether?

Comment: Thanks a lot Willem!